# Grafana using OIDC

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, grafana

I've followed Grafana docs and I'm not sure how to configure the Grafana with OpenID connect.
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/

We already configured several applications with OpenID connect which works OK.

What I need is to configure the OpenID connect to Grafana.

What we have:

> 1. ClientID
> 2. Client Secret
> 3. expose Grafana publicly

In addition, we exposed our Grafana publicly and should configure "/redirect" to it.

Our issuer servers configs support the following:

> "issuer" : "https://accounts.fds.com"
>
> "authorization_endpoint": "https://accounts.fds.com/oauth2/authorize"
>
> "token_endpoint":"https://accounts.fds.com/oauth2/token"
>
> "response_types_supported":["code","id_token","token"]
>
> "scope_supported": ["openid"]

From the doc This callback URL must match the full HTTP address that you use in your browser to access Grafana, but with the prefix path of /login/generic_oauth"
So we provided this also, my question is what should I do further, what is mandatory ?

Should I create some application or this is just configuration task?

We are using Grafana  `7.1` .

I've configured it like following:

```
grafana:
  enabled: true
  namespaceOverride: ""
  grafana.ini:
    server:
      root_url: http://a725be449-30559695.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/
    auth.generic_oauth:
      enabled: true
      client_id: foo_clientid
      client_secret: foo_secert
      scopes: "openid"
      auth_url: https://accounts.fds.com/oauth2/authorize
      token_url: https://accounts.fds.com/oauth2/token
#     api_url: https://${domain}/userinfo. //Not sure what this
      allow_sign_up: true
```

In the 'root_url' field I've put the the link to our grafana which redirects to to /login

Not sure what is the **API_URL**???, what should I provide there?
When deploying the app I see **new button** with `sigh in with oAuth` when I click I got error: "OpenID provider cannot process the request because the configuration is incorrect. Please contact your system administrator." any idea ?

In addition if I want to configure redirect url which property should I use?

**update**

I was able to see the redirect working but I got this error, any idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your used OIDC client should have configured this redirect URL:

```
http://a725be449-30559695.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/login/generic_oauth
```

That will be requested redirect URL by Grafana based on your `grafana.ini` configuration.

I hope you know that https protocol is required for OIDC.

Comment: 1+ , thanks a lot, please see my update, any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @NINS this is not a chat, it is not good idea to change the scope of the question just because you have another error + it is saying "Check the Grafana server logs" and you didn't provide any server logs. I bet you have a problem with the userinfo request/response.